# Convert a string such as as 'a' to number in lua

Tags: lua, type-conversion

Is there anyway I can get the ASCII code for characters such as 'a' in Lua? tonumber doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`string.byte(...)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) does that:

```
print(string.byte("a")) --> 97
```